# After adding 2012 server to domain, cannot RDP using domain accounts

Tags: windows, domain, rdp

I just added a win2012 server (VM) to the domain (controlled by win2008r2 DC) Everything is fine except that I cannot RDP to the server using domain credentials (enterprise admin) from any PC EXCEPT the domain controller... RDP to the 2012 server using local account still works just fine.

When I try to RDP from my workstation with Domain acct it just gives me the wrong password error, but like i said using exact same credentials but initiating from within the DC it connects right up.

I think I'm missing something simple here. But can't find anything on this please help!

Also pardon my ignorance I'm very new to Windows administration.

P.S I can RDP to the DC from my workstation no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in as `DOMAIN\user` or `user@DOMAIN`? If you just type the username you would log as a local account by default. You have to specify the domain when logging in as a domain user.